# What's the Spirit Point cost of Shapeshift: Spirit?

Tags: dnd-3e, races, l5r-2e, rokugan

[*Fortunes and Winds*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1887953620) (2002) for *Legend of the Five Rings, Second Edition* and *Dungeons and Dragons, Third Edition* presents the new race Shapeshifter, each subrace of which gains a handful of Spirit Points with which to buy Spirit Abilities. However, no Spirit Point cost is provided for the the Spirit Ability **Shapeshift: Spirit** (*Fortunes and Winds* 24).

Given the Spirit Ability's power (that is, Shapeshift: Spirit allows *any* level 17 or higher Shapeshifter to use a *polymorph*-like effect to change form for 1 hour/level into a specific extraplanar being of the creature's Hit Dice or less and employ that being's supernatural abilities), I expect the cost to be prohibitive. Is there errata for *Fortunes and Winds* that gives this Spirit Ability a Spirit Point cost, and, if there isn't, what is a reasonable Spirit Point cost for this ability?

(Keep in mind that an argument can be made that the Spirit Ability Shapeshift: Spirit has a Spirit Point cost of 0 as the penalty for *failing* to end properly the Shapeshift: Spirit effect means, essentially, the Shapeshifter becomes for 1 day an NPC that behaves in fashion appropriate to the assumed form—which is, potentially, crossing-the-streams level of bad. I currently find that a *weak* argument, but if a convincing case can be made, that's cool.)

---

***Note:*** Overuse of Initial Capitalization can be Blamed on AEG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the whole thing and feel, that it is an oversight, since every other Shapeshifter ability has an associated Spirit Point cost and the **Shapeshift: Spirit** is the capstone ability of the **Shapeshift** tree.

I would price it at 8pts, in lieu with other powerful capping abilities like **Reincarnation (8pts)**. At least it should cost 6pts, to be more expensive then **Shapeshift: Object (5pts)**

Comment: Thank you for your input. I'd feared this question forgotten. You have my sympathy and my respect for trudging through *Fortunes and Winds.*

Comment: L5R is my main RPG, so I am always happy to add my two zeni :D

Comment: In that case, if you've time and inclination, there's also [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/78459/8610) that's likely right in your wheelhouse, and [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/74346/8610) that might be. An expert opinion is always welcome.

Comment: Eight points is what the only [*L5R2E* errata](http://www.kazenoshiro.com/forge/1/2ndEditionErrata.php) that I can find puts it at, so—barring AEG for no reason putting back on the Web actual for-reals errata—this looks good.